# Weighted empirical distribution function (ECDF) in python

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to generate weighted empirical CDF in python. I know `statsmodel.distributions.empirical_distribution` provides an `ECDF` function, but it is unweighted. Is there a library that I can use or how can I go about extending this to write a function which calculates the weighted ECDF (EWCDF) like [ewcdf {spatstat}](http://lojze.lugos.si/%7Edarja/software/r/library/spatstat/html/ewcdf.html) in R.

Answer (score 0):

`Seaborn` library has `ecdfplot` function which implements a weighted version of `ECDF`. I looked into the code of how `seaborn` calculates it.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = np.arange(100)
weights = np.random.randint(10, size=100)

estimator = sns.distributions.ECDF('proportion', complementary=True)
stat, vals = estimator(sample, weights=weights)
plt.plot(vals, stat)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Seaborn* provides *ecdfplot* which allows you to plot a weighted CDF. See [seaborn.ecdf](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.ecdfplot.html). Based on deepAgrawal's answer, I adapted it a little bit so that what's plotted is CDF rather than 1-CDF.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = np.arange(15)
weights = np.random.randint(5, size=15)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((sample, weights)).T, columns = ['sample', 'weights'])
sns.ecdfplot(data = df, x = 'sample', weights = 'weights', stat = 'proportion', legend = True)
```